# Install Qt without admin rights

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to download Qt. I tried to download it from [Qt's website](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) but this gives me an exe file and since I've got a limited account when I try to run it it asks for an admin password. I've searched the web for a way for a limited account to install Qt but I haven't found anything. Could someone please help me find a solution?

In case it matters, I'm using Code::Blocks and Windows 7.

Comment: There is a zip file from QT Archive Mirror downloads [**here**](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.1/5.1.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1.zip.mirrorlist) .

Comment: What do you want to achieve with installinng Qt?

Comment: Is using a (Linux) virtual machine for your Qt stuff an option?

Comment: @hyde no privileges to install Qt IMO implies no privileges to install and run a VM.

Comment: @ddriver Not necessarily, a VM could be installed by default, precisely to allow doing development work on a locked down host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [this ZIP file with Qt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sD9KvTHVEwSmYPBM0GU7cG1k2oZc7yUn/view?usp=sharing). All you have to do is unzip the ZIP file (which will take time) and place the files it contains in the right folder, nothing that requires administrator privileges. I recommend you put the contents of the ZIP file in `C:\Qt`, otherwise it might not work correctly (if this folder doesn't already exist, you can create it without administrator privileges and if it does exist, Qt is probably already installed on your computer in which case you don't need to do anything). I've also posted Qt's license agreement as it is in the installer program [here](https://justpaste.it/1d6nk) since Qt wants you to read it before you use Qt.

Furthermore, I recommend using Qt Creator to make your Qt projects instead of Code::Blocks, because it's difficult to get Qt5 to work with Code::Blocks and Qt5 is the version of Qt used on both this website and Qt's installer (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192936/using-qt5-in-codeblocks)) (if you find a way to get Qt5 to work with Code::Blocks, all the better, maybe you could even answer the question for which I posted a link). Qt Creator is included in the ZIP files on my website and to use Qt with Qt creator, all you have to do is include the right header files, no linking is needed. The path of Qt Creator is in the table on the bottom of the website.

Comment: That gives a technical answer, but the OP should also care about social & legal issues, so ask explicitly permission.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, that's a good point. I will post a link to the Qt FAQ and the Qt license agreement on my website to make sure that whoever downloads Qt from there has easy access to the legal stuff

Comment: Qt wont run from just about any folder without patching it.

Comment: @ddriver Thank you for telling me that. I recommended on my site to install it in C:\Qt (which can be created without administrator rights if it doesn't already exist), that's the folder that I installed Qt in and from which I created the ZIP files.

Comment: You might want to investigate if it will work with symlinks, so it could be put somewhere else and instead create a symlink in the location it expects to be.

Answer (score 4):

You could download the free software source [code](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0.zip) and compile and [build](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html) it on your machine (that takes about a whole night, or maybe more). Don't forget to [configure](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html) the build appropriately (I don't know Windows, but on Linux I'll suggest explicitly setting the `-prefix` to some writable directory ...). Before starting, *ask explicitly your boss for permission* (if you violate your company policies, you can be fired at once), and ask for guidance from someone knowing your operating system better than you do. You might need to change your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) too.

Alternatively, ask permission to install and use a Linux distribution.

PS. Be sure to get permission to do something (even if technically you can do it alone).

Comment: I've got no idea how to do that. Could you please explain how to do? And if it's possible, I would like another solution which is easier. But if there isn't any and if I find out how to do, I will try that.

Comment: Better ask some help from some more experimented colleague who would set up things as needed on your machine.

Comment: Actually on a fast machine it takes about an hour if you use multithreaded build.

Answer (score 2):

You can download an archived distribution of [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/Base/). After you extract and run it, you can use its packet manager to download numerous packages, including Qt. The only downside is you will have to settle for the version it provides, which is a little old, currently 5.5.1. You can install by typing:

```
 pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-qt5 // for 32bit build or
 pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5 // for 64bit
```

This will install Qt and all dependencies automatically. Make sure your antivirus is not running in the final stage, because it can mess with the binary patcher that patches Qt to run from its current installation folder (because advanced software like Qt apparently cannot work without hard-coded paths).

You can even get a static build of Qt, which is quite useful, just add a `-static` to the package name.

Just in case you were wondering - MSYS2 is a build environment, it can come quite in handy, for getting ready to use libraries, or for building libraries which require a build environment. You can build Qt without it, however, it is a very slow process that may fail, and even though it is not complex to do, I would not recommend it as a first option.

If you still decide to build it from source, [there is a detailed guide which will get you through the process](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html).